# My QGIS project won't open - unable to unzip .qgz file

Tags: qgis, qgz

I created a QGIS project yesterday, and saved it in one of my user's folder. The file extension is qgz. Today I can't open it anymore. In the project home folder in QGIS it says Unable to unzip file and then file path where the file is.

Comment: You could try unzipping the qgz file with 7zip, winrar or winzip and see if you can open the containing qgs file then.

Comment: I have the same issue - but I have a mac, so can't use 7zip, winrar or winzip :( Any other ideas?

Comment: Try to open the project not by double clicking, but from the `Menu Project / Open`  in QGIS

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you copied the project `qgz` file, while QGIS was running the project.
If the case then open the copied `qgz` file with 7zip (or another zip file reader) and remove any files except the `qgs` file; save and try to open again.